# Regex to add <li> tag using OCMOD

Tags: regex, xml, opencart, vqmod

I want to add a menu in opencart admin page using OCMOD. I want to modify the menu in `menu.tpl` file but I think it requires regex as the `<li>` must be the last before `</ul>` tag. Can somebody help? The `<ul>` tag is like this:

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $location; ?>"><?php echo $text_location; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $language; ?>"><?php echo $text_language; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $currency; ?>"><?php echo $text_currency; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $stock_status; ?>"><?php echo $text_stock_status; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $order_status; ?>"><?php echo $text_order_status; ?></a></li>
      <li><a class="parent"><?php echo $text_return; ?></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $return_status; ?>"><?php echo $text_return_status; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $return_action; ?>"><?php echo $text_return_action; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $return_reason; ?>"><?php echo $text_return_reason; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $country; ?>"><?php echo $text_country; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $zone; ?>"><?php echo $text_zone; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $geo_zone; ?>"><?php echo $text_geo_zone; ?></a></li>
      <li><a class="parent"><?php echo $text_tax; ?></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tax_class; ?>"><?php echo $text_tax_class; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tax_rate; ?>"><?php echo $text_tax_rate; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I know it is posible to add my menu after

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $geo_zone; ?>"><?php echo $text_geo_zone; ?></a></li>
```

Using this operation

```
<file path="admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search>
            <![CDATA[
            <li><a href="<?php echo $geo_zone; ?>"><?php echo $text_geo_zone; ?></a></li>
            ]]>
        </search>                       
        <add position="after">
            <![CDATA[
            <li><a href="<?php echo $my_menu; ?>"><?php echo $text_my_menu; ?></a></li>
             ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

But I want to add my menu to the last of the list (after `<li>` that contains `<ul>`). I think it should use regex to make this works. Please somebody help, thank you.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this via regex. However if you know the occurrence you can use index (or can in vqmod anyway) and just use `</ul>` in the search with `index="3"` and use `position="before"`

Comment: Yes, your comment answered my question actually. Thank you for your help. I don't really understand regex anyway, so I thought my problem was related with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use just a standard search and specify the `</ul>` you want to using the `index` in your `<add>` tag specifying which of them is the right one to place the content before/after. Remember that other extensions can do the same and add sub-menus that will alter the index. Regex isn't a viable option for this.

So the operation for your question should be like this:

```
<file path="admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl">
<operation>
    <search index="2">
        <![CDATA[
        </ul>
        ]]>
    </search>                       
    <add position="before">
        <![CDATA[
        <li><a href="<?php echo $my_menu; ?>"><?php echo $text_my_menu; ?></a></li>
         ]]>
    </add>
</operation>
```

The index starts from `0`, we add new list before the last `</ul>` which is in index `2`.